# Is there a way to get the list of indexed words from Marklogic universal index

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am working on Marklogic tool
I am having a database of around 27000 documents.
What I want to do is retrieve the keywords which have maximum frequency in the documents given by the result of any search query.
I am currently using xquery functions to count the frequency of each word in the set of all documents retrieved as query result. However, this is quite inefficient.
I was thinking that it would help me if i could get the list of words on which marklogic has performed indexing.
So is there a way to retrieve the list of indexed words from the universal index of marklogic??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would use something like this in MarkLogic:

```
(
    for $v in cts:element-values(xs:Qname("myelem"))
    let $f := cts:frequency($v)
    order by $f descending
    return $v
)[1 to 10]
```

This kind of functionality is built-in in the `search:search` library, which works very conveniently.

But you cannot use that on values from `cts:words` e.a. unfortunately. There is a little trick that could get you close though. Instead of using `cts:frequency`, you could use a `xdmp:estimate` on a `cts:search` to get a fragment count:

```
(
    for $v in cts:words()
    let $f := xdmp:estimate(cts:search(collection(), $v))
    order by $f descending
    return $v
)[1 to 10]
```

The performance is less, but still much faster than bluntly running through all documents.

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

What if your search contains multiple terms? How will you calculate the order?

What if some of your terms are very common in your corpus of documents, and others are very rare? Should the count of "the" contribute more to the score than "protease", or should they contribute the same?

If the words occur in the title vs elsewhere in the document, should that matter?

What if one document is relatively short, and another is quite long. How do you account for that?

These are some of the basic questions that come up when trying to determine relevancy. Most search engines use a combination of term frequency (how often do the terms occur in your documents), and document frequency (how many documents contain the terms). They can also use the location of the terms in your documents to determine a score, and they can also account for document length in determining a score.

MarkLogic uses a combination of term frequency and document frequency to determine relevance by default. These factors (and others) are used to determine a relevance score for your search criteria, and this score is the default sorting for results returned by search:search from the search API or the low-level cts:search and its supporting operators.

You can look at the details of the options for cts:search to learn about some of the different scoring options. See 'score-logtfidf' and others here:

http://community.marklogic.com/pubs/5.0/apidocs/SearchBuiltins.html#cts:search

I would also look at the search developers guide:

http://community.marklogic.com/pubs/5.0/books/search-dev-guide.pdf

Many of the concepts are under consideration by the XQuery working group as enhancements for a future version of XQuery. They aren't part of the language today. MarkLogic has been at the forefront of search for a number of years, so you'll find there are many features in the product, and a lot of discussion related to this area in the archives.

Answer (score 1):

*"Is there a way to retrieve the list of indexed words from the universal index of marklogic?"* No. The universal index is a hash index, so it contains hashes not words.

As noted by others you can create value-based lexicons that can list their contents. Some of these also include frequency information. However, I have another suggestion: `cts:distinctive-terms()` will identify the most distinctive terms from a sequence of nodes, which could be the current page of search results. You can control whether the output terms are just words, or include more complex terms such as element-word or phrase. See the docs for more details.

http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/5.0doc/apidoc/SearchBuiltins.xml&category=SearchBuiltins&function=cts:distinctive-terms

Answer (score 0):

I have used cts:distinctive-terms(). It gives mostly wildcarded terms in my case which are not of much use. Furthur it is suitable for finding distinctive terms in a single document. When I try to run it on many documents it is quite slow.

What I want to implement is a dynamic facet which is populated with the keywords of the documents which come up in the search result. I have implemented it but it is inefficient as it counts the frequency of all the words in the documents. I want it to be a suggestion or recommandation feature like if you have searched for this particular term or phrase then you may be interested in these suggested terms or phrases. So I want an efficient method to find the terms which are common in the result set of documents of a search.

I tried cts:words() as suggested. It gives similar words as the search query word and the number of documents in which it is contained. WHat it does not take into account is the set of search result documents. It just shows the number of documents which contain similar words in the whole database, irrespective of whether these documents are present in the search result or not

Comment: this should probably be a comment on Blakeley's answer above